# How to disable hover effect on bootstrap custom button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and this is probably a stupid problem, but I can not disable hover effect on `fa-chart-line` icon here:

```
<h5>
  <span class="btn btn-circle blue1-icon"> 
    <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>
  </span> My Title
</h5>
```

CSS:

```
.blue1-icon {
  background-color: #019993;
  color: #fff;
}

.blue1-icon:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


.btn-circle:hover {
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: none !important;  
 }


.fa-chart-line:hover  {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you put your html?

Comment: Sorry just fixed the html.

Comment: Could you show a demo of your problem? I can't seem to replicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm having a hard time determining the effect exactly, but you could always use `pointer-events`.

```
.btn-circle {
    pointer-events: none;
    display: inline-block; /* For added support */
}
```

Links:

- [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp)

Comment: the question is how to disable the hover event! Not ALL the events

Comment: @Ricardinho Hmm, what unexpected behavior do you foresee occurring from using `pointer-events: none`?

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

You need to set color of .btn to white on hover. I have added !important only for demo purposes. Ideally, if you load your css after bootstrap css, you no need to provide !important.

Also, no need of text-decoration which you have used in your code.

```css
.blue1-icon {
  background-color: #019993;
  color: #fff;
}

.blue1-icon:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


.btn:hover {
  cursor: default;
  color: white !important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h5>
       <span class="btn btn-circle blue1-icon"> 
            <i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span> My Title
   </h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap4 according to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) you simply add `disabled` to a button tag (not the css class), like so:

```
<h5>
  <button class="btn btn-circle blue1-icon" disabled> 
    <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>
  </button> My Title
</h5>
```

At least, this is how it works for buttons.

Hope this is helpful and not too far off-topic (using button instead of span and bootstrap4 instead of 3).